# Displaying moneygram and western union dollar rates in site

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to display the dollar rates of both moneygram and western union on my site but haven't found any information on how this could be accomplished. How can one go about starting?

Thanks

Comment: you need to find finance api like Google Finance Or Yahoo Finance API that provides your desired data